# How to put a View on top of a FloatingActionButton?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm trying to achieve something like that: [image]

I tried to put a TextView on top of it by changing the elevation, but it falls under the floating button anyway, any suggestion? :S (can surely use an ImageButton that looks like a floating button and put a view on top of that, but I wonder if there is a better way)

Comment: Show the code that you have tried.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the xml:

```
android:src="@drawable/image" //uses a drawable as a background for your button
```

Or in java, like this:

```
fab.setImageDrawable(Drawable);
```

Comment: yeah but how to put the src image on the edge of the floating abtn? (I'm guessing it can be manipulated in drawable) but even then I have to be able to insert diffrent values in the view that is on top of the fbtn if I use 'android:src' it seams like it gona get preaty convoluted to do that...:S